# Receive wcf Callback in Asp.net Core application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-2.0

I am having a Duplex WCF Service hosted on console. This is tested and worked fine.

I want to consume this WCF service in Asp.net Core. I have done this using this https://medium.com/@narinkaew/using-wcf-soap-services-in-net-core-fb13180c4eda Consume WCF in Asp.net Core.

I am able to get response, but I am not getting any callback. Its just keep waiting.

I have uploaded the Code https://filebin.net/pf9eplqjncc0octj.

ClinicWcfService - is wcf Service Application

HospitalServiceHost - WCF Service Hosted on Console

ServiceEngineersDesk - is Asp.net Core Application.

Can someone tell me how to get a WCF callback in asp.net core application?

Comment: How about showing your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this from my side.
Instead of creating instance of interface of the wcf service, create a instance of interface implementation.

Now this class exposes the event of the callback. Just subscribe to it

After a some struggle i was able to found out.